# Can I control bandwidth allotment?

Tags: internet, download, bandwidth, upload

Is there an application or any tweak that can do that?
I mean putting more concentration of bandwidth on downloads rather than uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use QoS packet analyzing on your router to give certain applications (ports) more bandwidth. More here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you're using to download.
uTorrent allows you to control that. i believe transmission on Ubuntu allows you to as well. I'm not sure about download managers, though - that's just torrents.